# Compare two web pages from different environments

Tags: testing, automation, protractor, cucumber

I currently have a QA and a training environment. I want to test if a particular web pages display the same objects. ( i.e both the pages must show the same inputs, links, tabs, textareas, etc) from both the environments. I currently run e2e tests with a protractor cucumber framework. Is it possible to write a code which does this comparison and outputs the mismatches(if any) within the pages from QA and training.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1. Taking the screenshot for the pages in both environment and
   compare them
2. Comparing the source of the page

But first option would be very easy and effective

use below code for taking the screenshot

```
public static void takeSnapShot(WebDriver webdriver,String fileWithPath) throws Exception{
        TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)webdriver);
        File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File DestFile=new File(fileWithPath);
        FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
    }
```

Use the Sikulix API for comparing an image with the current screen

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
screen.setAutoWaitTimeout(30000); 
screen.wait(new Pattern("img/image.PNG")).click();
screen.wait(new Pattern("img/image.PNG").exact()).click();
```

Or you can use [Appli tool](https://applitools.com/) for comparing two image files.